# Error on topographic correction

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, remote-sensing

I tried to modify the Daniel's script to apply Tan's topo correction method.
Here is Tan's method.
https://geog.umd.edu/sites/geog.umd.edu/files/pubs/1-s2.0-S0034425713001673-main.pdf
https://code.earthengine.google.com/3d1dc100ec3fe9f68e12ef996536ef55

```
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-115.51858045584667, 45.29650713146457],
          [-115.51858045584667, 44.2632748294202],
          [-113.60146619803417, 44.2632748294202],
          [-113.60146619803417, 45.29650713146457]]], null, false);

//Apply topographic correction on all S2 scenes of year 2019 over my ROI

function cloud_mask(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  var out = image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
      .select("B.*")
      .copyProperties(image);
  return out;
  }

var dem = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003");

function topoCorr_IC(img){

  // Extract image metadata about solar position
  var SZ_rad = ee.Image.constant(ee.Number(img.get('MEAN_SOLAR_ZENITH_ANGLE'))).multiply(3.14159265359).divide(180).clip(img.geometry().buffer(10000)); 
  var SA_rad = ee.Image.constant(ee.Number(img.get('MEAN_SOLAR_AZIMUTH_ANGLE')).multiply(3.14159265359).divide(180)).clip(img.geometry().buffer(10000)); 
  // Creat terrain layers
  var slp = ee.Terrain.slope(dem).clip(img.geometry().buffer(10000));
  var slp_rad = ee.Terrain.slope(dem).multiply(3.14159265359).divide(180).clip(img.geometry().buffer(10000));
  var asp_rad = ee.Terrain.aspect(dem).multiply(3.14159265359).divide(180).clip(img.geometry().buffer(10000));

  // Calculate the Illumination Condition (IC)
  // slope part of the illumination condition
  var cosZ = SZ_rad.cos();
  var cosS = slp_rad.cos();
  var slope_illumination = cosS.expression("cosZ * cosS", 
                                          {'cosZ': cosZ,
                                           'cosS': cosS.select('slope')});
  // aspect part of the illumination condition
  var sinZ = SZ_rad.sin(); 
  var sinS = slp_rad.sin();
  var cosAziDiff = (SA_rad.subtract(asp_rad)).cos();
  var aspect_illumination = sinZ.expression("sinZ * sinS * cosAziDiff", 
                                           {'sinZ': sinZ,
                                            'sinS': sinS,
                                            'cosAziDiff': cosAziDiff});
  // full illumination condition (IC)
  var ic = slope_illumination.add(aspect_illumination);

  // Add IC to original image
  var img_plus_ic = ee.Image(img.addBands(ic.rename('IC')).addBands(cosZ.rename('cosZ')).addBands(cosS.rename('cosS')).addBands(slp.rename('slope')));
  return img_plus_ic;
}

function topoCorr_TanC(img){
    var img_plus_ic = img;
    var mask1 = img_plus_ic.select('B8').gt(-0.1);
    var mask2 = img_plus_ic.select('slope').gte(5) //apply to terrain has slop greater than 5 degree
                            .and(img_plus_ic.select('IC').gte(0));
    var img_plus_ic_mask2 = ee.Image(img_plus_ic.updateMask(mask2));

    var bandList = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12']; // Specify Bands to topographically correct

    function apply_TanCorr(bandList){
      var method = 'TanC';
      var out = img_plus_ic_mask2.select('IC', bandList).reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.linearFit(), // Compute coefficients: a(slope), b(offset), c(b/a)
      geometry: ee.Geometry(img.geometry().buffer(-5000)), // trim off the outer edges of the image for linear relationship 
      scale: 500,
      maxPixels: 10e13
      }); 
      var out_a = ee.Number(out.get('scale'));
      var out_b = ee.Number(out.get('offset'));
      // out_a and out_b can be null giving error when calculating out_c
      // var out_c = ee.Number(out.get('offset')).divide(ee.Number(out.get('scale')));      
      var out_c = ee.Algorithms.If(
        out_a, 
        ee.Number(out.get('scale')),
        ee.Image() // Masked image
      )

      //apply the TanC correction
      var TanC_output = img_plus_ic_mask2.expression("image - cvalue * (ic - cosZ)", {
        'image': img_plus_ic_mask2.select(bandList),
        'ic': img_plus_ic_mask2.select('IC'),
        'cosB': img_plus_ic_mask2.select('cosS'),
        'cosZ': img_plus_ic_mask2.select('cosZ'),
        'cvalue': out_c
      });

      return ee.Image(TanC_output);
    }

    var img_TanCorr = ee.Image(bandList.map(apply_TanCorr)).addBands(img_plus_ic.select('IC'));
    var bandList_IC = ee.List([bandList, 'IC']).flatten();
    return img_TanCorr.unmask(img_plus_ic.select(bandList_IC))
                       .addBands(mask1.rename('initMask'))
                       .addBands(mask2.rename('corrMask'));
  }

var S2_original = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                    .filterBounds(roi)
                    .filterDate('2019-01-01','2019-12-31')
                    .filterMetadata('MEAN_SOLAR_ZENITH_ANGLE', 'less_than', 85)
                    .map(cloud_mask);

var S2_topo_corr = S2_original
                    .map(topoCorr_IC) 
                    .map(topoCorr_TanC);

Map.addLayer(
              S2_original.select(['B4','B3','B2'])
              .reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([25])).clip(roi),
              {min:0,max:0.2},
              'Original', true
);

Map.addLayer(
              S2_topo_corr.select(['B4','B3','B2'])
              .reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([25])).clip(roi),
              {min:0,max:0.2},
              'Corrected', true
)
```

However, I got the following error.

```
Corrected: Layer error: ImageCollection.reduce: Error in map(ID=20190101T182741_20190101T182744_T11TQK):
Image.multiply, argument 'image1': Invalid type. Expected: Image<unknown bands>. Actual: Float.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have removed the casting to `ee.Image` in the `If()` statement. Adding it back get this to work again.

```
  var out_c = ee.Algorithms.If(
    out_a, 
    ee.Image(ee.Number(out.get('scale'))),
    ee.Image() // Masked image
  )
```